# How to filter methods in netbeans profiler with two or more criteria with AND operator

Tags: java, regex, netbeans, filter, profiler

I'm trying to filter methods, that would be in a package "cz" and the name of the methods would contain "merge". So I type "cz merge" but this places an OR operator between the two. Is there any way how to force AND operator in between the two? I was trying it with regular expressions, but I realized I have no clue how to write such an expression. I tried to get familiar with the syntax, but was not able to get anywhere in a reasonable time.

Is this achievable via regular expression (only)? There are three options in the filter: contain/not contain/regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for a regular expression looking for a string containing both 'cz' and 'merge' in any order, this one should work for you:

`(merge.*cz|cz.*merge)`

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if it is a netbeans bug or something, but your regex did not work to filter strings that contains both in any order.

Comment: I'm sure it's a valid expression, but it's not clear to me where in Netbeans you want to use it? I have netbeans 7.1.2 but can't find anything to filter 'methods'. You can use this expression with the normal find function of netbeans though, won't that work? Another check, with 'string' I mean a single line. This expression wont work on multiple lines. This one might though: `(merge(.\n)*cz|cz(.|\n)*merge)`

Comment: NetBeans -> Profiler -> Open any Saved CPU profiling snapshot, or create some by profiling some application -> "Combined" (Under the call-tree view of methods with their total time are other tabs, you can view of the snapshot. Press the combined one.) -> "Method name filter" (Right above the tab selection) -> write any such expression, where you want to find a method containing two substrings. I was looking for something like cz.fi.mu.merge() (but much longer)